# How to extend & delete SP2013 web application on a SP2013 server having two front end servers?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, web-application

I want to extend SP2013 web application on a sharepoint server having two front end servers and one back end server. How to do that? I have extended one web application but it was on sharepoint server having one front end server. Is it the same way we have to do? or we have to also extend the web application on another front end server.

Comment: Extend web application the same way as you did. You use host header, which points to IP of NLB (which load balance your two WFEs). Don't forget about AAM for correct web application working.

Comment: What is NLB could you provide some relevant links..

Comment: Is that I have to provide the public url for alternate access mapping of sharepoint site of both the front end servers?

Comment: I did'nt defined any host header for the extended web application which I did it for server having single front end. Why it is required?

Comment: It depends. If you want to access your SP site interneally from short internal name like http://intranet  , but for example for extranet usage, you want to have different url like https://extranet.company.com.

Comment: why do you need to extend web application?

Comment: Network Load Ballance (NLB) used to load ballance user requests, when more then one web fron end server is used. You alredy have some url for your web application, and in DNS it should be mapped to web forn end server or NLB sluster IP, if your have two or more WFEs. Even how do you load ballance the requests? https://i-technet.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC378512.gif

Comment: We need to extend the web application because we are designing different UI for the site and we want it in different zone intranet. Also we want the same content db for it.

Comment: Yes, then you extend web app it uses the same content DB. If you want different url for extended zone, then don't forget to configure the AAM.

Answer (score 1):

Extend web application as you did in 1WFE farm. You don't need to do anything on each WFE. But if you've got web applications provisioned as HTTPS, you'll need to take the appropriate measures to get the SSL cert configured on the servers, that is something SharePoint won't do for you.

For more info look at this guide: [Extend web applications in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg276325.aspx)

Think about host names, sometimes it is better to have.

And also take a look at this answer: [SharePoint WebApplication publishing](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/6fbf58cf-c5b8-444d-934c-24e9e37198c0/sharepoint-webapplication-publishing-with-nlb-and-2-vips?forum=sharepointadmin)

Comment: Yes I will give it a try and get back to you..